# Creating a new measure in PowerBi - difference between aggregating by SUM() and AVERAGE()

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Completely noob here, so I bet this is a silly question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm new to PBI and I keep struggling with creating a New Measure. The DAX for the new measure I'm trying to create is:

`total_size_gb = 'index-name'[statistics.storage_size]+'index-name'[statistics.repository_size]`

My data source is a Elastic Search and the documents I'm looking at have the following format - each id has one storage_size and one repository_size:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "statistics": {
            "storage_size": 5,
            "repository_size": 10
        },
 ...
}
```

For a reason I can't understand, I'm being forced to use a formulate for aggregation like SUM() or AVERAGE() so my formula would look like:

`total_size_gb = SUM('index-name'[statistics.storage_size])+SUM('index-name'[statistics.repository_size])`

Trying to create a table with all id's and storage_size + repository_size, but results seem to vary if I use SUM() or AVERAGE().

Can you help me understand why?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: An expression like `'index-name'[statistics.storage_size]+'index-name'[statistics.repository_size]` makes sense only when evaluated in the context of a single row. It would therefore only be appropriate as a computed column. Measures implicitly calculate over all rows (with filters applied, if any) and so they always aggregate over multiple rows, hence the `SUM`. And, obviously, using `AVERAGE` here would lead to completely different results, since, well, an average isn't a sum. Even if you had a `total_size` computed column, a measure over it would still use `SUM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks like a JSON format. When you load JSON into the Query Editor in Power BI, it will be transformed into a table. Still in the query editor, you can then add a custom column to add up storage size and repository size (for whatever reason you would want to do that. Doesn't seem to make much sense).

It looks to me like you are wrapping a SUM() function around the field name quite unneccessarily. It is a bad habit that I have seen people do in Excel. If you want a line by line result, you don't need to do a SUM(). Just add up the items you want to add up, using the '+' operator.

Then load the query into the data model. After that, you can use DAX to calculate measures. Total and average whole columns. That kind of stuff is done in DAX, whereas data cleanup and creating additional columns with line by line calculations can easily be done in Power Query (the Query Editor).